# For the four dimensional $U$ and $V$ subspaces of the $\mathbb{R}^6$ is U+V=$\mathbb{R}^6$. What is the dimension of the $U\cap V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I assume that I can use the following:for the subspaces $U_{1},U_{2}$of the  $V$ vectorspace is true, that $dim U_{1}+dim U_{2}=dim(U_{1} \cap U_{2})+dim(U_{1}+  U_{2})$

I assume that the answer is 2, because both subspaces give us the whole $\mathbb{R}^6$, is my answer correct?

Comment: I don't mean to sound disparaging, but it seems you are literally saying "$4+4=6+2$, is my answer correct?" which I think is not a very good use of a question. I think you probably have very little doubt about the reasoning you gave (which is perfectly fine... there is barely any way to go wrong at all) and rather you are suffering from a lack of confidence.  Please don't post check-my-solution questions just to bolster your confidence... but if you really have a concrete concern about a solution you've come up with, feel free to ask about it.

Comment: You have the right formula; you know that $\mathrm{dim} U_1=4$, $\mathrm{dim} U_2=4$, and $\mathrm{dim}(U_1+U_2)=6$. Now just do the arithmetic.

Comment: Perhaps you can put the full assumptions in the body of the question itself, rather than have them in the title only.  [For example, the title is worded in an unusual way, and it is not clear to me if $U+V = \mathbb{R}^6$ is an assumption (given in the title), or if "is $U + V = \mathbb{R}^6$?" is part of the question you are asking.]